# Android Studio missing icon

Tags: java, android, android-studio, icons

My Android project has a problem... I can open it in Android Studio. But I can not launch it,  the background icon has vanished. In the settings, instead of button launch, it has only a deflected button. Here's my AndroidManifest.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.check_meal">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent..MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intenactiont.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW."/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi, @ksg232 have you checked whether your ic_launcher exists or not?

Comment: Try adding -> android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" to the application tag in your manifest